# How can I use 'theme' made with 'createMuiTheme()' inside 'makeStyles()'?

Tags: material-ui, makestyles

I have made `customTheme` using `createMuiTheme()` and I used it in the `<ThemeProvider>`.
Now, I want to make some custom styles using that `customTheme` inside the `makeStyles()` function. But `makeStyles()` is not getting my `customTheme`. It gets the default theme.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { createMuiTheme, makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';

const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#f0f'
    },
  }
});

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  box: {
    height: '100px',
    width: '100px',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
}));

export default function App() {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>

      <div className={classes.box}>
        makeStyles
      </div>

      <div style={{
        height: '100px',
        width: '100px',
        backgroundColor: customTheme.palette.primary.main
      }}>
        inline style
      </div>

    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Screenshot:
[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDiFX.png)

As can see in the Screenshot, the first `<div>` has default deep blue color of Material-UI that is using `makeStyles`.

The second `<div>` has the custom color, that is using inline style.

So, how can I use the `customTheme` in `makeStyles()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ThemeProvider to wrap over App component, as per my understanding theme provided will be applied to react components wrapped under it. since "makeStyles div" is just an element styles didn't apply to it.

Codesandbox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-custom-theme-f354x